# Hill cipher -- obtain matrix key

Tags: hill-cipher

I have to solve Hill's cipher. I have only cipher text: `CGQIYN` and key: `CFDG`. I don't know how to decrypt it, because in all videos I've watched they knew the Matrix key from the beginning. I don't want you to solve it, but I am really hopeless and I absolutely don't know how to do it. If you can provide me some procedure, I will be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: hint: usually the matrix is written as [[C F][D G]].

Comment: Sorry, but still I don't know how to obtain key matrix. I tried everything but I got only gibberish text. In all videos and texts everyone knows the key matrix from the start and doesn't explain it.

Comment: @hlll123 You can comment here to request clarifications; you should always be able to comment on qustions and answers when you are the asker.

Answer (score 1):

The key is 4 characters long, therefore it must be in a 2 × 2 matrix. The numbers in this matrix must be the inverse of the encryption key matrix, and there are various methods to work this out (see this [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion)). Once the matrix inversion has been calculated, you multiple it through each part of the cipher text in their respective 2 × 1 matrices

Answer (score 1):

The key is 4 long, so should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. In members of $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ `CFDG` becomes $2, 5, 3, 6$  in the usual `A` becomes $0$, `Z` becomes 25 encoding.

After some experimenting I found that we make this into the encryption matrix

$$K = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5\\ 3 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

where encrypting is done by multiplying a row of plain text (as members of $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$) from the left by $K$ to get a cipher row.

So first we need the inverse of $K$, and $\det(K)= 2\times 6 - 3 \times 5 = -3 = 23 \pmod{26}$ which is invertible, as it should, as $\det(K)^{-1} = -9 = 17 \pmod{26}$.

The inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ equals $\det(A)^{-1}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} d & -b\\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$ when $\det(A)$ is invertible (works in any commutative unitary ring) and applying this to out $K$, we get (check this!)

$$K^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 24 & 19\\ 1 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

and this allows us to decrypt $CG\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 24 & 19\\ 1 & 8 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \text{ci}$$

while `QI` becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix} 16 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 24 & 19\\ 1 & 8 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}  \rightarrow \text{ce}$$ and finally

`YN` decrypts as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 24 & 13 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 24 & 19\\ 1 & 8 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 17 & 14 \end{bmatrix}  \rightarrow \text{ro}$$

So I suspect `cicero` to be the required solution. The method of encryption and decryption should hopefully be familiar to you, and also the method of finding matrix inverses.