# HillCipher, cannot get the key, Given the plaintext and the ciphertext

Tags: encryption

I'm doing a project for my Data security course, and it's to implement the HillCipher Algorithm in C#.I've successfully Implemented the Encryption and Decryption.

however there is one function missing and it's the Analyse function which takes the Plaintext and the Ciphertext and it should return the Key I know that the key will be 2x2.I am not sure how I can do that,
I know that the : C = KP , and so K = C*P-1
but the problem is for a given testcase : plaintext is : "paymoremoney" , ciphertext : "tqssypkoqviw"
I cannot find the inverse of the plaintext, it's not square matrix.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. You need to consider the plaintext and ciphertext 2 by 2 as you did for the encryption and decryption. In some pairs, you may get a non-invertible matrix so switch to another ( note that that can be still solvable, too).

Comment: Since a project see this; [Hill cipher -- obtain matrix key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68852/18298)